# Unable to parse JSON from Firebase DB for Google Maps Heat Map Layer

Tags: json, google-maps, firebase, heatmap

Can't seem to find any error, but it appears that the code here isn't parsing the JSON db from Firebase properly thus not allowing Google Maps to read it and display the heat map.

```
   bikeLinesRef.on('value', function(snapshot)
        {
            dataArray.clear();
            for (var route in snapshot.val())
            {
                for (var i=0; i<route.length; i++)
                {
                    for (var j in snapshot.val()[route][i])
                    {
                        if (j==0 && i>0)
                        {
                            continue
                        }
                        else                            
                        {
                            dataArray.push(new google.maps.LatLng(snapshot.val()[route][i][j].jb, snapshot.val()[route][i][j].kb));
                                    //console.log(j + ' ' + snapshot.val()[route][i][j].jb, snapshot.val()[route][i][j].kb);

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Not sure what the question is, could you add more details? An error message or stack trace would help immensely.